# Вывод последовательности введенных данных по окончанию ввода

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, input

> На вход программе подается последовательность слов, каждое слово на
> отдельной строке.
>
> Концом последовательности является слово «КОНЕЦ» (без кавычек).
>
> Напишите программу, которая выводит члены данной последовательности.

Вот что я пробовал:

```
a = input() 

while a != 'КОНЕЦ' and a != 'конец': 
    print(a) 
    a = input()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста предоставьте код, который вы уже написали, до того как задать вопрос.

Comment: a = input()
while a != 'КОНЕЦ' and a != 'конец':
    print(a)
    a = input()

Comment: Ознакомьтесь [ask]

Comment: @Эникейщик Но у него уже БЫЛИ попытки решения

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия-3-8 "1. Кратко опишите вашу конкретную проблему в заголовке . 2. Сначала опишите проблему, потом добавьте код". Оба пункта отсутствуют.

Comment: Ну а минус мне за что? Круто

Comment: так как все таки должен происходить вывод - по окончании ввода (как сказано у вас в заголовке) или параллельно (как в вашем коде)?

Answer (score 2):

Ваш код почти правильный, только

- вместо *немедленного вывода* введенного слова (командой `print(a)` в цикле)
  нужно

  - слова сначала *только сохранять* (напр. в списке)
  - и только *после введения всех слов* (т.е. окончания вашего цикла) их выводить на экран:

```
words = []                               # сначала пустой список
a = input()

while a != 'КОНЕЦ' and a != 'конец': 
    words.append(a)                      # здесь разница
    a = input() 
    
for word in words:                       # вывод сохраненных слов
    print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для python 3.8 и выше

```py
result = []
while not (a := input('Введите слово: ')).lower() == 'конец': 
    result.append(a) 
print(*result, sep='\n')
```

Для версий python 3 - 3.7

```py
result = []
a = input('Введите слово: ')
while a.lower() != 'конец':
    result.append(a) 
    a = input('Введите слово: ')
print(*result, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

В задание чётко не указаны многие детали, но если следовать описанию, то:

```
input_words = []
while (a := input()) != 'КОНЕЦ':  # чётко сказано, что концом ввода является только слово «КОНЕЦ» большими буквами, а слово «конец» вполне может быть частью последовательности
    input_words.append(a)
print(*input_words)  # формат вывода не описан, поэтому вывожу через пробел
```

Также не сказано, является ли слово «КОНЕЦ» частью последовательности, но я подразумеваю, что нет, так как это команда